# UITableViewController similar to Add Event Table View Controller of iOS7 calendar app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What is the proper approach to creating a table view controller that is used for user input and has all static cells in which some are text fields, some are date pickers, switches, etc.

My use case is exactly the same as the calendar application's.  Table View Controller pushed modally when the user hits the plus button and the user enters data into a few text fields, flips some switches, and picks some dates.

Are the cells for this type of table view created programmatically using the provided datasource methods?

[image: Calendar Add Event Table View Contoller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards are the only way to create static table views. You define an entire scene, and can define all cells as you like. You don't even need custom cell subclasses, you can connect labels and text fields defined in the cells as properties of the view controller directly, for easy access.

I have implemented a very similar view controller in our app using a Storyboard, where the entire scene is defined within the storyboard, including alert time and invitees. I implemented the initial view controller as a navigation controller, just like the `EKEventEditViewController`.

Comment: So does this still require a table view controller on the storyboard? Maybe there is a decent tutorial you can share?

Comment: @JuJoDi Here is one: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_an_Xcode_5_Storyboard_to_Create_a_Static_Table_View